# Dynamic Width of Widgets

Tags: widgets

Ok, I'm using the following code for up to 6 widgets in a sidebar

```
function s57d_sidebar1_params($params) {

$sidebar_id = $params[0]['id'];

if ( $sidebar_id == 'sidebar-1' ) {

    $total_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    $sidebar_widgets = count($total_widgets[$sidebar_id]);

    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="', 'class="span' . floor(36 / $sidebar_widgets) . ' ', $params[0]['before_widget']);
}

return $params;
}
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params','s57d_sidebar1_params');
```

The resulting code when there are widgets in the sidebar displays like:

```
<section id="text-2" class="span6 widget widget_text">
<div class="span6 widget-wrap">
<h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Text 1</h4>
<div class="textwidget">Text 1</div>
</div>
</section>
```

The class is being assigned to the section and then again to the div.  I don't want the div to also get the class.  What is wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, at least I was able to style the section, leaving the css in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your specific question, it may provide a solution for you.  With a proper CSS selector, you can target a DIV of class "span6" with rules that are separate from a SECTION of class "span6".

In your CSS, write your selectors like this:

```
div.span6 { rules; rules }
section.span6 { differentrules; }
```